ggplot string variable on the x-axis
I am trying to create this graph in R from the database named df1. The variable on the x-axis is a string variable (a combination of months and years). This is the R code that I have tried. The x-axis is not in the correct order. The graph generated in Excel (which is the correct grpah) and the one generated using ggplot are not the same.
Any suggestions to solve my problem is appreciated.
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% pivot_longer(-1) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=timeWindow,y=value,group=name, color=name))+
    geom_line()

What I am getting now
Dataset(df1)
What I am supposed to get (this is generated from Excel)

Can you please share a sample of your data as code so that others can more easily reproduce the problem? Try using dput(df1) and pasting the contents in your question. It sounds like you probably want to convert the timeWindow data type to a date object (or a factor that you order).

library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame (
  timeWindow = c(
     "2/2007-1/2015",  "3/2007-2/2015",  "4/2007-3/2015",   "5/2007-4/2015", 
     "6/2007-5/2015",  "7/2007-6/2015",  "8/2007-7/2015",   "9/2007-8/2015",
    "10/2007-9/2015", "11/2007-1/2015", "12/2007-1/2015",  "1/2008-12/2015", 
     "2/2008-1/2016",  "3/2008-2/2016",  "4/2008-3/2016",   "5/2008-4/2016", 
     "6/2008-5/2016",  "7/2008-6/2016",  "8/2008-7/2016",   "9/2008-8/2016", 
    "10/2008-9/2016", "11/2008-1/2016", "12/2008-1/2016",  "1/2009-12/2016", 
     "2/2009-1/2017",  "3/2009-2/2017",  "4/2009-3/2017",   "5/2009-4/2017", 
     "6/2009-5/2017",  "7/2009-6/2017",  "8/2009-7/2017",   "9/2009-8/2017", 
    "10/2009-9/2017", "11/2009-1/2017"),
  rO = runif(34, 1.0, 1.2),
  r1 = runif(34, 0.6, 1.0),
  r3 = runif(34, 0.4, 0.6)
)

df %>%
  # assume that timeWindow is ordered chronologocally in the dataframe
  mutate(timeWindow = forcats::fct_inorder(timeWindow)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-timeWindow) %>% 
ggplot()+
  geom_path(aes(x = timeWindow, y = value, group = name, color = name))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))


Thanks. How to set the xlim for this variable? Suppose I want a gap of 20 observations on the x labels.

scale_x_discrete(breaks = df$timeWindow[seq(1, nrow(df), 20)])
